# Need more clarity on file command usage in linux?

Tags: linux, arm, cross-compiling

I have built a linux image for ARM on Ubuntu. I was curious to use the file command on the image file created in arch/arm/boot directory. When i execute the following the command

```
balaji@balaji-virtual-machine:~/meraj/linux-stable/arch/arm/boot$ ls
bootp  compressed  dts  Image  install.sh  Makefile  zImage
balaji@balaji-virtual-machine:~/meraj/linux-stable/arch/arm/boot$ file Image
Image: data
balaji@balaji-virtual-machine:~/meraj/linux-stable/arch/arm/boot$ file zImage
zImage: data
balaji@balaji-virtual-machine:~/meraj/linux-stable/arch/arm/boot$
```

It gives not much information. I would like to know if this is expected behaviour or not?

Answer (score 2):

From file manpage:

> The type printed will usually contain one of the words...
>
> ... "data" meaning anything else (data is usually 'binary' or non-printable).
>   Exceptions are well-known file formats (core files, tar archives) that
>   are known to contain binary data.

Also...

> Any file that cannot be identified as having been written in any of
>   the character sets listed above is simply said to be 'data'.